# save the image to the temporary folder once selected in a file options then save it to the folder after submit cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, upload, temporary

I am trying to save the picture to temporary folder first once the user selected it from the file options. And then save it to move folder after submitting the form.

Here is the code for uploading:

```
$id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
            $userData = $this->User->findById($id);
            if ($userData['User']['id']  === $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')) {
                $this->set('userData', $userData);   
            } else {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('You are not allowed to this page!'));    
            }

            move_uploaded_file($fileTmp,  WWW_ROOT.'files\Users'.DS.$uid.DS.$fileInfo['tmpFileName']);
```

This code allow me to save it directly to the folder without saving it to temp folder.

I want to save what is being previewed.

Here is my javascript in previewing:

```
//preview
    $("#file").change(function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        var imagefile = file.type;
        var imagesize = file.size;
        var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg","image/gif"];
        $('.upload-submit').prop('disabled',false).css('opacity',1);
        if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2]) || (imagefile==match[3])))
        {

            $("#message").html("<p id='error' style='color:red;'>Please Select A valid Image File</p>"+"<h4  style='color:red;'>Note</h4>"+"<span id='error_message'  style='color:red;'>Only jpeg, jpg, gif and png Images type allowed</span>");
            return false;
        } else if (imagesize > 6000000){

            $("#message").html("<p id='error' style='color:red;'>Your file size is higher than the allowed size (6MB)</p>");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            var imgData = reader.onload;        }
    });
    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $("#file").css("color","green");
        $('#image_preview').css("display", "block");
        $('#previewing').attr('src', e.target.result);
        $('#previewing').attr('width', '250px');
        $('#previewing').attr('height', '230px');
    };
```

and my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/users/profileimg_edit" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadimage">
                                <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
                                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="upload-image-btn" >

                                <div id="image_preview"><img  id="previewing" src="/images/noimage.png" width="80" height="80" />
                                <div id="message"></div>
                                </div>

                                <button class="upload-submit"> Upload Image </button>

                            </form>
```

With this code the user can view what did he/she selected and save it, but I want is to save it first in a temporary folder.

Thank you for help that will be given.

Comment: "This code allow me to save it directly to the folder without saving it to temp folder." AND "With this code the user can view what did he/she selected and save it, but I want is to save it first in a temporary folder."  ???

Answer (score 0):

First move the picture to a temporary directory on the the server (say, `WWW_ROOT . 'tmp' . DS . $fileInfo['tmpFileName']`), then use that path in your preview (so the URL becomes someting like `http://my.server.com/tmp/b5c8f033dfaa.jpg`). Then, when the user is done previewing, move the file to the final destination.

However, you must keep track of the temporary filename (`$fileInfo['tmpFileName']`) because that info is lost if you go to the next page. You can put it in the URL or store it in the Session object.

You might also want to add cronjob to remove old uploaded files from the `tmp` directory, because there will usually be some abandonded file uploads, etc.